# Java LocalDateTime Formatter Issue

Tags: java, timestamp, localdate, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

I am currently working with Java LocalDateTime Formatters where i want to parse an Date from a String. I boid the problem down to the following code. This is using the Formatter correctly to create a String of this pattern, but it is not able to read the exact same String. And i have problems to find out why that is so.

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
        String stringTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);
        System.out.println(stringTime);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringTime, formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
```

What makes this even more confusing for me, if i insert a caracter in the pattern like in the code below the function works and translates a date to a string and back.

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm-ssSSS");
        String stringTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);
        System.out.println(stringTime);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringTime, formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
```

I get the following stacktrace

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20220421154548090' could not be parsed at index 0
> at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
> at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
> at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)

I would be very glad for some advice here.

Comment: Do you want to parse the `String` to a `LocalDateTime` and then print the very same `String` as output? If yes, use the method `LocalDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter)` for the output instead of `dateTime` only (so use `System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter));`. The `Exception` thrown was a bug, I guess. If you used Java 9 or higher, you would not get that bug. I just used Java 11 for it and it worked.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Note that your general confusion is misleading: Imagine a formatter that only prints the hours. Obviously legal, and obviously not possible to go from LDT to string and back to an LDT if that's the format. The error almost sounds like there's a newline or unicode BOM or `\0` char at the start of your input string. Did you run this _actual_ code? Verbatim, copy/paste, right now? If truly, edit the question and include your default locale (`Locale.getDefault()`). I don't see how this pattern is affected by it, but perhaps we can then reproduce.

Comment: It’s a known bug in Java 8. Fixed in Java 9. [Link: JDK-8031085 : DateTimeFormatter won't parse dates with custom format "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8031085)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the request from @deHaar I tryed different Java- Versions. With zulu-8 this issue is appearing, with higher Versions like zulu-17 the code works just fine. So I'll have to use a higher version or find a workaround. Thank you for your replys.

Comment: The workaround is in the duplicate link.